# Rally SDK :filter Rally data by setting up context workspace and project

Tags: sdk, rally

Below I'm trying to filter Rally data by setting up context workspace and project but its not working .. What am I doing worong?  I also looked at another similar question posted here but it was not helpful for me.

```
 Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {
                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                    model: 'UserStory',
                    autoLoad: true,
                     context: {
                workspace :'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/workspace/2004571051'
                project: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/project/5022032422',
                projectScopeUp: false,
                projectScopeDown: false
}
                    filters: [
                {
                   property: 'Name',

                    value: 'story about a Product X'
                }
],
                    listeners: {
                        load: this._onDataLoaded,
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: Your code looks good... Do you not get any results?  If you inspect the request to hierarchicalrequirement.js in the network tab of your browser tools do you see project=/project/5022032422 in the query string?

Comment: Yes , this is not returning anything.. I pasted https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/project/5022032422.js in the URL and its returning the correct project. I tried the same with workspace.

Comment: What version of the sdk are you using?  2.0p5?

Comment: I'm using 2.0p5. I was able to make it work . I had to remove workspace from the code.